# Import into Address book all email addresses from emails sent of a Mail backup

Tags: mac, apple-mail, address-book

I would like to import all email addresses from all the emails sent (fields TO:, CC: and BCC:)  in Mail (Mac OS X) and add them to Address book in OS X Lion, is it possible?

Comment: sounds like a programming problem. I expect. You need a mail client that has a nice scripting interface. Some thing that will let you process all you emails and write to a file. I doubt it will be very long or difficult to create a script that make a .csv file which you could then use to import your emails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if this covers BCCed recipients, but this should do the trick for you:

1. In Mail, from the **Window** menu, choose **Previous Recipients**.
2. Notice that entries already in your Address Book are marked with an icon at the left.
3. Click any item in the list, then type **⌘-A** to *Select All*.
4. Click the **Add to Address Book** button in the lower-right of the *Previous Recipients* window.

Comment: this did the trick!